Issue with Navigator or Bloc?
On my code I can't navigate to another page, but the result is successful and the showLoadingAlertDialog is displaying and working fine, the terminal result is successful as well.
What I tried:

Use physical device.

Make sure context is valid from the Widget tree.

debugPrint and it prints the correct results.

LocalFilesPage() is working fine.

Tried flutter_bloc: ^8.1.0 and flutter_bloc: ^8.1.5
Future<void> addImageCameraGalleryCubit(context, {required String fileName}) async {
emit(AddImageLoading());
showLoadingAlertDialog(context, 'Uploading Image please wait...', true);

try {
  final result = await addCameraGalleryImageUseCase.call(fileName);
  debugPrint('>>> 2 RES $result');
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LocalFilesPage()));
  emit(AddImageSuccess(file: result));

} catch (e) {
  emit(AddImageFailure());
  buildAlertDialog(context, 'Error', 'Failed to add image', true);
}

}



Terminal result:
I/flutter (20651): >>> 2 RES File: '/data/user/0/com.redjaguarapps.fusion/cache/image_cropper_1712684502739.png'


Don't post your code as a screenshot. Post it as text so people can try your code without having to manually retype it out.

you should do showLoadingDialog on AddLoading state in UI. as well as do push on AddImageSuccess state in UI. context in cubit? expect for a troubles...

@Abion47 I added code as text

What does this mean? "I can't navigate to the screen" ? What happens exactly?

@A.Ktns it is showing the showLoadingAlertDialog(); and it prints '>>> RES File /data/user' path image location, this is a success response, but I am not able to move to LocalFilesPage() screen, that screen is working fine

I guess U are navigated there but because the state changes to success your app is rebuilding. Better Remove the Navigation from there and put it in a BlocListener. I will put this as an answer cause doesn't fit here.

How to navigate with BlocListener. Use your own BLOC.
BlocListener<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  listenWhen: (previous, current) {
    // return true/false to determine whether or not
    // to invoke listener with state
    // you want to Navigate after the async call returns the file and emits the success page.

    return previous is AddImageLoading && current is AddImageSuccess;
  },
  listener: (context, state) {
    // do stuff here based on BlocA's state
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LocalFilesPage()));

  },
  child: YourWidget(),
)

